Use as const for only one property of an interface
I have this
interface MyType  {id: string; label: string };

const t = [
  {id: 'a' as const, label: 'A'}, 
  {id: 'b' as const, label: 'B'}
] satisfies Array<MyType>;

so that I can later do
type Ids = (typeof t)[number]['id'];

so Ids will be 'a' | 'b';
This works well. But I would like to do it in a way that I don't need to define as const in each id. Also 'label' should be mutable, so
const t = [
  {id: 'a', label: 'A'}, 
  {id: 'b', label: 'B'}
] as const satisfies Array<MyType>;

is not a solution for me.
How can I do it?

You can do that with a helper function using two generic parameters like so:
interface MyType {
  id: string;
  label: string;
}

const createArray = <
  U extends string,
  T extends ({ [K in Extract<keyof MyType, "id">]: U } & Omit<MyType, "id">)[],
>(
  arr: T,
) => arr;

const t = createArray([
  { id: "a", label: "A" },
  { id: "b", label: "B" },
]);

type Ids = (typeof t)[number]["id"];
//   ^? type Ids = "a" | "b"

TypeScript Playground

Cool, but now I have a dependency between MyType and '{ id: U; label: string }' I modified it a little
interface MyType<U extends string> {   id: U;   label: string; }  and
const createArray = <U extends string, T extends MyType<U>[]>(

@de3 Good point. I updated my answer so createArray refers to keys of MyType instead of using literals. That way you won't have to modify MyType.
